# Balancing dataset for survival analysis

Tags: python, survival, unbalanced-classes

So I'm using survival analysis to help identify customers at risk of churning. As of now, I've been using a hugely imbalanced dataset that consists of 99.5% of customers in the majority class (i.e. not churned) and 0.5% churned. To improve my model I've randomly undersampled the majority class such that the ratio between the minority and majority classes is only 1/3, which resulted in improvements when compared to using the full dataset.

However, in order to avoid removing data points which can be important, I would like to try oversampling techniques such as SMOTE, etc but I don't know how well this would suit survival models, because the `duration` (target variable) depends on a churn date/time which is the result of the difference of two variables in the dataset (`date_client_churned` + `date_client_joined`). Isn't generating new examples going to mess with the distribution of these two variables and as such produce erratic results? Has anybody dealt with this kind of imbalance in the dataset for survival analysis, and if so what was your approach? Is it really necessary to balance the dataset for survival analysis?

For reference, the survival models that I've used are: Cox Proportional Hazards, Random Survival Forests and Gradient Boosted Trees with Cox loss.

Just to clarify how I compute the `duration` variable: For time `t = 0` I'm using the date a customer signs a contract with the company, given by `t_born`, and for the end date I'm using either a) the churn date `t_churn` if `t_churn < t_study`, where `t_study` represents the end of the study period (`t_study=t_born+6`, `t_study=t_born+12`, `t_study=t_born+24` months); b) `t_study` otherwise. The `duration` column will then be given by the difference `t_churn - t_born` if `t_churn < t_study`; `t_study - t_born` otherwise.

Comment: It seems at first glance that the `duration` should be the _difference_ of two dates, `date_client_churned - date_client_joined`, to represent the length of time that the individual was a client. Please edit the question to explain what you are using for the reference `time = 0` for individual customers and why you are using the sum of those two dates for the `duration` survival time. Please do that by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted. Also, note that this might better be handled by a cure model that accounts for individuals that never have events.

Comment: [Misconceptions abound when it comes to class imbalance, and statistics sees little problem.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6349/247274) Why do you think the class imbalance is problematic in your case?

Comment: The fact that you would create a new topic when this issue has been covered extensive on the site.  Thinking class imbalance is a problem is equivalent to not understanding the field of statistics.

Comment: @EdM Thank you for the suggestion, I've added an explanation on the OP.

Comment: @Dave Thank you for the article! I'm not saying it's problematic per se, but I've seen a significant boost in performance and lower training time when I used random undersampling compared to a model using the full dataset.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Not so much in the case of survival analysis. I'm not saying it's a problem, but as I said in the above comment, I've seen performance improvements when using random undersampling, hence why I wanted to explore other techniques, I just didn't find much information online on balancing techniques in survival models other than some adapted models.

Comment: Improvement of what metric(s)?

Comment: lift score (the first 10 percentiles) and the c-index

Comment: Particularly on the c-index I'm getting around 30% improvement.

Comment: Any apparent improvement that comes from disrespecting the sample sizes is an illusion.  And don't use the c-index to compare models.  It's not good at that.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to try oversampling techniques such as SMOTE, etc but I don't know how well this would suit survival models...

As the comments on this question and many pages like [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/28500) demonstrate on this site, it's not clear that SMOTE or any type of biased over/under-sampling suits *any* type of model well. You then necessarily bias the intercept of the model and thus all probability estimates (unless you back-correct for the biased resampling). It's not clear that even relative log-odds or log-hazard estimates are improved, as you don't have any more cases than you started with.

Unbiased resampling by bootstrapping at the original sample size, however, is a very useful technique for validating and calibrating models, including survival models. See the `validate()` and `calibrate()` functions of Frank Harrell's [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) for example. Provided that you resample by case so that each set of `t_born`, `t_churn` and `t_study` is kept together, there is no problem.

I suspect that your apparent improvement with SMOTE would disappear if you evaluated performance of the modeling process by bootstrap resampling or (with tens of thousands of cases) repeated train/test splits.

Finally, it's not clear that a continuous-time survival model like a Cox model is the best choice for data like yours, where there is apparently a very large ratio of cases to observation times. A discrete-time model--a set of binary regressions, including time as a predictor, on appropriately structured data--could be preferable. In particular, it would naturally handle your large proportion of censored cases that might be considered "cured" in a survival model. At the least you should consider a cure model that combines survival over time with a binary "cured" outcome, as the types of model you have used implicitly assume that every case eventually experiences the event in question.